# Cannot deploy android app on Visualstudio2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, deployment

I cannot deploy android app on VisualStudio 2019.

Deployment failed
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000: Mono.AndroidTools.RequiresUninstallException: The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.

Yes i know, there are many threads out there that say use: adb unsinstall packagename.

I read all these thread and tryed these things out, without having luck.

I also tryed to increase the version number of my app, to be sure to have a number that is not used. Also it does not work.

My question, is there any other thing that i can try?
These things i have tryed:

- Uninstall all libs from the device of mono runtime.
- Uninstall of the app is not possible because the app is not installed.
- adb uninstall packagename
- pm uninstall --user 1 packagename

Comment: Visual studio version? i mean like 16.x.x?

Comment: 8.4.7 (build 17)